# Use file from MAUI project to create a source file compile time in referenced project/package c#

Tags: c#, .net, maui, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I am stuck at this issue for sometime and looking for implementation ideas and/or code snippets.

So I have 2 projects:

A dotnet maui project which has a xml file.

A class library which does something.

Now The MAUI app references the class library through a package or a project reference.

I want to create a c# class in the Class library with property names in sync with key value pairs from the xml file present in the MAUI app, at compile time.

So if the xml file has tags with key “key1” of type string. Then it will create a get set property with key1 as Property Name.

I tried different approaches but didn’t seem to work.

SourceGenerators was one. But if you reference a source generator to the MAUI app to create a c# class, it will create it in the MAUI app and not the class library.

I have the code to create the c# class from the xml file but the approaches i had were incorrect.  Either I had to put a .xml in the class library to create a c# class using a source generator, or some other things which weren’t desired.

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a XY-problem. Either move the XML file into library or generate files in the main app.

Comment: I don't see how you can do that as part of solution build, because that is a "circular dependency" between main program and library. Neither can build first, because they both affect each other. IMHO, The xml file will have to be copied into the library. I don't know if there is any way to get that to automatically happen any time xml file's update timestamp changes.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve is it possible to have a generator in the second class library which access the files and creates the c# code. So I am looking at a class library which has a source generator which creates a c# class in the same project and also use the c# class within that project. And can use the file from maui using additionalFiles or some other build action set?

Comment: @GuruStron generating files in main app is not possible because I want to use the c# class in the class library to do things. It will essentially help create an api. And moving xml to the class library is not possible because multiple projects can have a reference to the class library and have a different  xml file but with different tags. So i’d want to create properties depending upon the .xml content.

Comment: @PrabhavMehra So how the library should determine which one of the XML files to use?

Comment: @GuruStron there is only one .xml file in the projects referencing the class library. when I tried the source generator approach. I set the build action to the xml as c# analyzer additional file and read it in source generator to create a c#. But at that time the file was in class library itself(which is not desired). Also it has a naming convention. So the name of the xml file for this functionality will stay the same in all projects ( that is expected from the app dev)

Comment: @PrabhavMehra _"And moving xml to the class library is not possible because multiple projects can have a reference to the class library and have a different xml file but with different tags."_ and _"there is only one .xml file in the projects referencing the class library"_ - you need to pick one, either there is one XML or multiple.

Comment: I meant that: multiple projects can have a reference to class library but only have 1 .xml following that convention. So for instance : project 1, project 2 and project 3 has a reference to the class library. Each one of them have a separate AppConfig.xml( standard naming convention, will stay the same for all). But each AppConfig.xml in all 3 projects, the tags MAY be different. @GuruStron

Comment: So which one of those multiple XMLs library should use to perform class generation?

Comment: @GuruStron short answer is all. MAUI Projects are not dependent on each other. So Project 1,2,3 all MAUI apps. each have their AppConfig.xml. It has keys as keyProj1, 2, 3 respectively. Now each one of them have a reference to this class library which exposes a class which does some work and also allows the apps referencing the class library, to do classLib.customClass.(keyProj1, keyProj2, keyProj3) depending upon the AppConfig.xml in proj. so Project 1 cant do classLib.customClass.keyProj2 because the source in the class lib, which is automatically  getting generated wouldn't have this key.